# How can I run composer install --dev on Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku, deployment, composer-php

How can I override default Heroku behavior about dependencies installation with Composer? AFAIK Heroku executes `composer install --no-dev` by default which is perfect for prod, but what if I intend to deploy PHP application in dev environment on the Heroku server?

So I need somehow to load dependencies from `require-dev` section of composer.json. Is it possible? Are there any hooks, events, etc. that could help me with it?

Answer (score 2):

Access heroku shell with command `heroku run bash --app=app-dev` in terminal

So, update composer components with `composer update --dev`